# OCAML Where is the error of compilation?

Tags: xcode, compilation, ocaml

Look at
 http://pastebin.com/VkXqenak
The compilator has a problems with compilation.
 What should I do?
 Where is an error ?

Comment: Pleas include your source on this page. If it's too long to include, try to reduce it to the smallest amount of code that shows your problem. Also, show what the error message looks like.

Answer (score 2):

`let x = a and let y = b in c` is not correct. You should either use `let x = a in let y = b in c`, or `let x = a and y = b in c`. Those are both syntactically correct, but don't have the same meaning: in the second case `x` is available in `c`, but not in `b` (as `and` defines `x = a` and `y = b` *simulatenously, one is not available for the other).